# Which version of SignTool is Visual Studio 2017 using?

Tags: windows-10, clickonce, visual-studio-2017, signtool

I have a project I migrated from Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 8.1 box to my new workstation, VS 2017 on Win 10.  Everything works fine until I try to publish to with ClickOnce.  The ClickOnce deployment succeeds but I cannot install the deployed application.  After a bit of research, I suspect the issue has to do with signing the manifest.  I updated the certificate to a SHA 256 cert, and now I cannot even build the application.  I get the error:

SignTool Error: Invalid option: /fd

I have installed the latest Windows SDK and I have *a* version of SignTool that supports /fd, but I still see the error in VS.  It appears there are many versions of SignTool scattered around my filesystem.  **How can I tell/change the one that Visual Studio is trying to use to sign my code?**

Comment: To the hater who downvoted this question, care to say why?  If the question is poorly written it would be helpful to know what would bring the question up to your standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs). Now the environment variables are set. At the prompt type:

```
where signtool
```

Now you have the path to the signtool.exe which Visual Studio 2017 is using.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message when migrating an old ClickOnce project from VS2018 to VS2017.

I found (and succeeded with) a tip to change registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` to make Windows to use newer SDK (in my situation SDK `v8.1A` was the most recent).

The original tip can be found here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a39b9f82-aaec-4bbd-8cb2-3cade50796ba/an-error-occurred-while-signing-failed-to-sign-bindebugapppublishprogramexe-signtool-error
(scroll down to answer by *nikidimi*)